# How should React-Redux work with non-serializable data?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Let's say you are writing a web-based word processor app, and because you don't want to deal with reading and writing a bunch of different document formats, you use a third party library for that part.

The library returns a class instance when you read a document, which you modify and then pass back to the library to save the document again.  You have to pass back the original instance to the library, so you need to keep hold of it while your app is editing the document.

Apparently you can't use this with React-Redux, because as soon as you try to save that class instance to the state, it complains that it's non-serializable.  Fair enough, but how then should you hold on to this class instance?

The documentation contains a section titled [Working with Non-Serializable Data](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data) which unfortunately doesn't actually tell you about working with non-serializable data, only that you should not do it.  But in the example above it is unavoidable, so surely there is some way to do this without just disabling all the warnings and hoping for the best?

Are you supposed to store things like this in a global variable/singleton and just put flags in the Redux store, like "documentOpen: true" and just refer back to the global object when you need the instance again?  That doesn't seem like a great way to do it, but I'm unable to find anything about how else to address this issue (other than just disabling the warning).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, per the docs, that kind of a class instance does not belong in the store state, because A) it's not actually "state", and B) it will not serialize correctly when used with the DevTools.

To me, that kind of a class instance either belongs strictly in the UI layer or in some kind of middleware, but it really depends on what that instance does and how you need to interact with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So in my case this object is providing information that the UI is supposed to allow editing of.  Continuing the document analogy, it might provide a list of Paragraph objects and some Image objects.  If the user right-clicks on an image to replace it with a new one, I would naturally assume the Image object in question goes into the state as that's the subject of the operation that the UI is then built around.  How would you put this in the UI layer, or am I misunderstanding the purpose of the store?

Comment: It _really_ depends on just what this "document instance" is and how the app interacts with it. Can you point to an example of this tool and its docs?

Comment: One example is [this library](https://github.com/Malvineous/gamearchivejs) (search the page for "quick start" for example code). It reads an archive (like a .zip file) and returns an `Archive` class instance.  This should be modified by UI actions as part of editing the file.  That `Archive` instance is then passed back to the library to turn it back into a .zip or similar, to be saved by the user.  The `Archive.files[].getContent` property is a callback function to read the content of a file inside the archive so it's very hard to serialize.

Comment: Yeah, that unfortunately definitely should not go into the Redux store.

Comment: So does that mean Redux cannot be used at all if your app needs to work with interfaces like this?

Comment: Maybe? Redux is very much designed around the assumption that the data you're working with in the store is plain JS objects and arrays. If your app is built around manipulating some kind of class, then it's likely that's not a good paradigm fit. There may be other ways to approach this problem, but it's hard to say without seeing your app's setup specifically.